# Exit child_process which execute sh file

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process

I use child_process to execute a sh file which download file with curl but when I use .exit() function the process didn't stop

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
let command = spawn('./download.sh', ["url", "name"])

setTimeout(() => {
    command.kill()
}, 2000);

command.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log("Data")
})

command.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log("exit");
})

command.on('close', (code, signal) => {
    console.log("close");
})
```

And this is my output

```
Data
Data
Data
Data
Exit
Data
Data
Data
...
```

This is my download.sh

```
curl {test url} --output test.mp4
```

But when I execute spawn with the curl command directly, the process stop so I don't understand why.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
let command = spawn('curl', ["test url", "--output", "test.mp4"])

setTimeout(() => {
    command.kill()
}, 2000);

command.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log("Data")
})

command.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log("exit");
})

command.on('close', (code, signal) => {
    console.log("close");
})
```

And this is my output

```
Data
Data
Data
Data
Exit
Close
```

If someone has an idea

Comment: Can you print the data itself to console.log?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean the contents of variable `data`, not the string `"Data"`

Comment: It was just for the example, but yes when I execute my download file with child_process I can print the content of data. My problem is just that when I kill the process the download continue.

Comment: I was asking you to *print the value of variable `data` that is being received by your code and show it to us*, not *if you can do it*. It might reveal what's going on.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question because nothing is received from stdout, all is received from stderr. But yes I get all the data, this is what I received : https://pastebin.com/pP8PD8nF

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you receive all the data in both cases, there is no problem.

Processes are asynchronous, so there is no guarantee that you will receive `exit` before `data` is finished. `exit` simply means that your process has exited at that point (and thus, the download should be complete). If the process wrote something to standard output/standard error, that data might still be stored in some buffers until it is consumed.

Comment: In fact what I want is just that I can stop the download and when I download something with .sh file the download continues even after the .kill() function is called.